# VSCode: Showing git history in sidebar for previous commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to show git history in the sidebar for previously committed changes? Once I commit, it goes away:

[image]

I can always `git reset --soft HEAD^` and un-stage to get to:

[image]

but then I have to either force push or force reset to sync with origin...

My ultimate goal is to be able to save the features and push to origin (to secure them), and still be able to see the changes I've made working on the current feature

Comment: I think no (but I'm not sure yet). Why do you really want this? How is it useful to you? (I'm not trying to gaslight you. I'm trying to understand where you're coming from)

Comment: @starball I would use it literally every day. I avoid commit until I have a decent checkpoint because I lose track of the changes I've made if I commit then continue working. It's super nice to be able to `git diff` and see what I've done to remind myself of direction

Comment: I'm confused. Usually people commit after completing some meaningful unit of change with code in a working state. Can't you write down what you're working on in some note-taking place to achieve what you just described?

Comment: @starball. Perhaps the last commit is used as an accumulator and new changes are added into that (by `--amend`) until joshp thinks he has a complete commit.

Comment: @md2perpe that sounds right. I do typically only commit after meaningful units of change, however, sometimes this can span a day or two (e.g. large breaking refactor). I typically prefer not commit if the code won't run/compile, hench wanting to commit and ammend

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting for this, unfortunately. VS Code only displays/controls the decoration for the current diff, until you commit.

I would suggest you to open a feature request in VS Code repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose), or look for some extension that could do the trick.

The only git related extension that I have installed is GitLens, and I don’t remember seeing this feature. On the other hand, if something *not git related* is an alternative for you, I would suggest you to take a look at Footsteps extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wattenberger.footsteps). It provides a good equivalence of the diff you are looking for, but with no connection to git commits.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks! I do think I want it to be related to git, otherwise I have to manage two tools, it's a cool extention tho!